# Integral inequality with two increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ be increasing functions such that $f\leq g$. Is there a constant $c>0$ (independent of $f,g$) for which there exists some $r\geq 0$ (possibly dependent on $f,g$) such that
$$\int_{x:f(x)\leq r\leq g(x)}g(x)dx+\int_{f(x)\geq r}f(x)dx\geq c\int_0^1g(x)dx ?$$

As an example, let $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x^2$. The integral $\int_0^1g(x)dx$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. On the left-hand side, for fixed $r$, the first integral is from $x=r$ to $x=\sqrt{r}$ and amounts to $\frac{1}{2}(r-r^2)$. The second integral is from $x=\sqrt{r}$ to $x=1$ and amounts to $\frac{1}{3}(1-r\sqrt{r})$.

Suppose $g(x)=x^t$ and $f(x)=x^s$ for $s\geq t\geq 1$. Then the right-hand side is $\frac{1}{t+1}$. The left-hand side is
$$\frac{r^{\frac{t+1}{s}}}{t+1}-\frac{r^{\frac{t+1}{t}}}{t+1}+\frac{1}{s+1}-\frac{r^{\frac{s+1}{s}}}{s+1}.$$

Comment: I think of this for half day and still no progress is made. To make it easier, I will restate the question using predicates: We want to show $\exists c > 0$ such that $\forall$increasing $f, g: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ with $f \le g$ $\exists r \ge 0$ such that $\int_{I_2} g + \int_{I_3} f \ge c \int_0^1 g$ where $I_1 = \{x \in [0, 1] \mid f(x) \le g(x) < r\}$, $I_2 = \{x \in [0, 1] \mid f(x) \le r \le g(x)$ and $I_3 = \{x \in [0, 1] \mid r < f(x) \le g(x)\}$. Notice $[0, 1] = I_1 \sqcup I_2 \sqcup I_3$.

Comment: Or its negation: $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ $\exists$increasing $f, g: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ with $f \le g$ such that $\forall r \ge 0$ $\int_{I_2} g + \int_{I_3} f < \varepsilon \int_0^1 g$ where $I_1, I_2, I_3$ are the ones defined above.

Comment: Try something like $\frac 1{x|\log x|}$ and $\frac 1{\sqrt x}$ near $0$ (then make the change of variable $x\mapsto 1-x$ and extend the graphs from a small neighborhood of $1$ to the entire interval $[0,1]$ in some reasonable way).

Comment: @fedja But if you are just giving two functions, there's always some $c$ that works. To show that no $c$ works it has to be a family of functions, doesn't it?

Comment: @Karo In that example the RHS is $+\infty$ while the LHS stays bounded regardless of $r$. If you want to turn it into a family of *integrable* functions, truncate at high levels.

Comment: @fedja But when you truncate at higher and higher levels, you can also increase $r$ accordingly. (Also, I wonder why you need the $|\log x|$. Wouldn't just $\frac{1}{x}$ have the same effects?

Comment: I've posted a discrete version [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289807/inequality-with-two-sequences), which is essentially the same but might be easier to discuss.

Comment: Have you tried working out the left-hand side for all $g(x)=x^t$, $f(x)=x^s$, with $s\ge t\ge1$ and seeing if it's true? For $g(x) = a^{x-1}$, $f(x)=b^{x-1}$ with $b\ge a\ge1$?

Comment: @Karo You achieve nothing by increasing $r$ because the LHS is bounded *uniformly* in $r$. And that is exactly why $|\log x|$ is needed. (Have you really bothered to compute the LHS in my example, I wonder?)

Comment: @fedja I'm not sure how to compute this, as I don't think $\frac{1}{x|\log x}=r$ has a nice closed form in $x$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, I computed this (see my edit), but it is not easy to see whether the statement is true.

Comment: @Karo No, but there is a nice closed form for $r$ in terms of $x$. Also, you can always estimate instead of an exact computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\newcommand {\diff} {\mathrm d}
\newcommand{\spc}[1] {\quad #1 \quad}
$$

For convenience, rewrite the inequality as $\max\limits_r \frac A B \ge c$, where

$$A = \int\limits_{f(x) \leq r \leq g(x)} g(x)\; \diff x + \int\limits_{f(x) \geq r} f(x)\; \diff x, \quad B = \int\limits_0^1g(x)\; \diff x$$

For $f(x) = \frac 1 {1 + s(1 - x)}$ and $g(x) = \frac 1 {1 + t(1 - x)}$, $s > t > 1$:

\begin{align*}
\frac A B
 & \spc = \left( \int\limits_{1 + \frac 1 t \left( 1 - \frac 1 r \right)}^{1 + \frac 1 s \left( 1 - \frac 1 r \right)} \frac {\diff x} {1 + t(1 - x)} + \int\limits_{1 + \frac 1 s \left( 1 - \frac 1 r \right)}^1 \frac {\diff x} {1 + s(1 - x)} \right) \Bigg/ \int\limits_0^1 \frac {\diff x} {1 + t(1 - x)} \\\\
 & \spc = -\; \frac {\ln \Big( \frac t s + \left( 1 - \frac t s \right) r \Big) + \frac t s \ln r} {\ln (1 + t)} \qquad \bigg| \qquad r \in \left[ {{\frac 1 {1 + t}}, 1} \right] \\
\end{align*}

We can exclude values of $r$ below $g(0) = \frac 1 {1 + t}$, as these are not good cadidates for maximizing $\frac A B$, for mostly obvious reasons.  Thus, $\max\limits_r \frac A B$ occurs at one of $r = \frac 1 {1 + t}$, $r = 1$, or some value of $r$ such that $\frac \diff {\diff r} \frac A B = 0$.

\begin{align*}
\frac \diff {\diff r} \frac A B
 & \spc = -\; \frac 1 {\ln (t + 1)} \left( \frac {s - t} {t + (s - t) r} + \frac t {sr} \right) \spc = 0 \qquad \bigg| \qquad r = \frac {t^2} {t^2 - s^2} < 0 \\
\end{align*}

The solution for $\frac \diff {\diff r} \frac A B = 0$ is spurious, as it lies outside $\left[ {{\frac 1 {1 + t}}, 1} \right]$.  Thus, we need only consider $r = \frac 1 {1 + t}$ and $r = 1$ for $\max\limits_r \frac A B$:

\begin{align*}
\frac A B \bigg|_{r = 1} & \spc = 0 \\
\frac A B \bigg|_{r = \frac 1 {1 + t}}
 & \spc = -\; \frac {\ln \Big( \frac t s + \left( 1 - \frac t s \right) \frac 1 {1 + t} \Big) + \frac t s \ln \frac 1 {1 + t}} {\ln (1 + t)}
   \spc = \frac t s + 1 -\; \frac {\ln \left(\frac {t^2} s + 1 \right)} {\ln (t + 1)} \\
\end{align*}

Obviously, $\max\limits_r \frac A B = \frac A B \big|_{r = \frac 1 {1 + t}} = \frac t s + 1 -\; \frac {\ln \left(\frac {t^2} s + 1 \right)} {\ln (t + 1)}$.

If we put $k = \frac t s$, $k \in (0, 1)$,

\begin{align*}
\max \frac A B & \spc = 1 + k -\frac {\ln (k t + 1)} {\ln (t + 1)}
 \spc \to k - \frac {\ln k} {\ln t} \spc \to k \qquad \bigg| \qquad t \to \infty
\end{align*}

We can choose $k$ arbitrarily close to 0, and then, by the above, choose $t$ such that $\max\limits_r \frac A B$ will be arbitrarily close to $k$, for the corresponding pair of $f(x) = \frac 1 {1 + \frac t k (1 - x)}$ and $g(x) = \frac 1 {1 + t(1 - x)}$.  Hence, **we can choose $f$ and $g$ such that $\max\limits_r \frac A B$ will be arbitrarily close to $0$**.